# What is the "context" meaning in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)

I think its a very interesting question:
What is the "context" meaning/concept in Android ?

Almost any things/object need context to working properly.
What is the "context" represented? An integer ? a block of memory ?? or .....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interface to global information about an application environment. This is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android system. It allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: I saw this on d.android.com but what people want is more clear answer :( still I can't understand this.